# Where's Nadja from?

Tags: character, the-hunt

In [*Jagten* (*The Hunt*)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2106476/), where's Nadja (the girlfriend who speaks halting Danish and is better at English) supposed to be from?

Comment: I don't think it's ever stated and her precise origins are not that relevant: she represents an outsider in this closed community.

Answer (score 3):

She's Polish.

I'm Polish, and when she said the word '*zdezorientowana*' and then quickly switched to the English translation 'confused' (timestamp: 58:25), I actually thought I misheard at first but then (timestamp: 59:10) she says an entire sentence in Polish: '*jak mnie uderzysz to kopnę cię w jaja*', which translates to 'if you hit me I'm gonna kick you in the balls'.

I also googled the actress' name (Alexandra Rapaport) because her Polish was so good (she really sounded like a native to me), and, yep, her parents are both Polish but she was born in Denmark.